# How to call a function inside an overloaded function

Tags: c++, overloading

There are two functions:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

uning namespace std;


vector<string> func1(vector<string> name1){
    vector<string> out;

    //do something and call our first function
    for(int i=0; i<100;i++){    
        out.push_back(func1(name1[i]));
    }
    return out;
}


string func1(string name1){
    string out;

    //do something

    return out;
}

int main(){
vector<string> vector_in;
vector<string> vector_out;
//generate text
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    vector_in.push_back(string("string"));
}
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    vector_out.push_back(func1(vector_in));
}
```

But when I try to call function `string func1(string name1)` from function `vector<string> func1(vector<string> name1)` I get an error:

> Error C2664 "std::vector> func1(std::vector>)": it is impossible to convert>argument 1 from "string" to "std::vector,std::allocator<_Ty>>"

What could be the problem?

Comment: I'd like to see an SSCCE. Also you can't return `int[]` from a function that wants to return `int`. In fact, I [totally can't reproduce that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee09eb4194507405) when creating a self-contained example.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. Besides the obvious errors in syntax etc., there's no way the behavior should be what you claim it is.

Comment: The second function would not compile.   The return type is `int`, but it is returning a pointer to a local variable (`out`).   And `int out[]` is an invalid declaration in C++ within a function.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz what is an sscce?

Comment: As a side note, such a function shouldn't be an overload. The first one is entirely enough, and it can be mapped over an array using higher-order functions such as `std::transform`.

Comment: @xaxxon: www.sscce.org

Comment: @Peter `int out[]` would not compile anyway there is no size to the array I would expect a `int out[something]` or use `new` for a dynamic array.

Comment: @xaxxon A [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: why not use [mcve] which actually has a link to what it means... ?

Comment: @xaxxon because I'm old and used to the old name, and now it's too late to edit in a link.

Comment: After your edit the program compiles and works fine. What's the problem now?

Comment: Your second function overload is calling the first function overload.

Comment: What is your platform and compiler? Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, @Peter , @MichaelWalz i juct past overload function `vector<string> func1(vector<string> name1)` before `string func1(string name1)`. I delete this question soon.:D

Comment: @engineer_7 don't delete the question, but clarify it.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, What exactly to clarify? I allowed a little carelessness, and tried to call a function that was not previously declared. I think that this issue is not serious.

Comment: @engineer_7 that's why there is the concept of  [MCVE]. If you had made an [MCVE]  you would probably have found the solution yourself.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, understood you, thank you. In the future I hope I will not repeat such stupidity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two distinct problems in your code:

1. in `func1(vector<string>)` you call `func1(string)` but the function is not yet defined. To correct this you can either put the function prototype `string func1(string name1);` before `vector<string> func1(vector<string> name1)` or you can put the whole `func1(string)` function before `vector<string> func1(vector<string> name1)`.
2. in `main()` you call `vector_out.push_back(func1(vector_in));`. The `func1` here is the `func1(vector<string>)` function, but the return type of this function is `vector<string>`. Now you call `vector_out.push_back` with an argument that is not a `string` but a `vector<string>` and there *is* no such function.

You still need to clarify the question and specify what `vector_out` should contain at the end.